# Notification Testing no record created during tests in notifications table

Tags: laravel, testing, notifications, phpunit

I am trying to test if notification is created in the database, in my local, this works as intended however the test environment has some strange behaviour.

```
    $user->notify(new ExampleNotification());

    $this->assertDatabaseCount('notifications', 1); 
//returns green with QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync but red with QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

...

```
class ExampleNotification extends Notification implements ShouldBroadcast, ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    public function viaQueues(): array
    {
        return [
            'database' => 'notifications'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function via(User $notifiable): array
    { 
        return ['database']
    }
```

ps: I do not use `Notification::fake()` anywhere in my tests

Does anybody know why the different queue connections would behave differently?

Comment: It might be because the non-sync notifications are queued but when testing there's no queue working usually running to handle the queued jobs

Comment: I think you are right, I did decide to stick with sync for this. If you put this as an answer I would gladly accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any queue driver other than the `sync` one works asynchronously i.e. when you send a notification job it will be queued and then the queue worker will remove it from the queue and then send the actual notification.

This means if you send a notification during a test, even if the queue worker is running the notification will most likely not be sent before the test is done.

To avoid this you should either use the `sync` queue or use `Notification::fake()` and just check if a notification would have been sent.